# Unable to get a handle on the auto-suggestion dropdown in an angular based website using python selenium

Tags: python, angular, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

I am trying to automate work-flow using python-selenium in a website made using angular. However, I am not able to automate auto-suggestion dropdown.

When i input the suggestion key using send-keys option for eg

`competence_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@formcontrolname='Competencies']") competence_input.send_keys('java')`

The above input generates a container  with multiple options from which i need to select one. The dom entries are presented below for reference.

```
<div class="cdk-overlay-container">
<div class="cdk-overlay-connected-position-bounding-box" dir="ltr" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;"><div id="cdk-overlay-6" class="cdk-overlay-pane" style="width: 295.555px; top: 279.07px; left: 463.195px;">
<div role="listbox" class="mat-autocomplete-panel ng-star-inserted mat-autocomplete-visible" id="mat-autocomplete-1">

<mat-option _ngcontent-edi-c192="" role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" style="font-size: small; opacity: 60%;" id="mat-option-136" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false"><!----><span class="mat-option-text"> Java Web Technologies </span><!----><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-option-ripple"></div></mat-option>

<mat-option _ngcontent-edi-c192="" role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator ng-star-inserted" style="font-size: small; opacity: 60%;" id="mat-option-137" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false"><!----><span class="mat-option-text"> Java - JMX </span><!----><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-option-ripple"></div></mat-option>
<!---->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**The code which i used is as following: **

`        try:
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
elements.until(
expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'mat-autocomplete-']")))

```
        competences = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//mat-option[@role='option']//span")
        print(len(competences))

        for item in competences:
            print('options are', item.text)
            if item.text == 'Java Web Technologies':
                item.click()
                break
    except:
        print('Item was not found or Dropdown did not appear')`
```

Any inputs on how to solve the issue would be highly welcome.

Thanks & regards,
Hari

```
        try:
            elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
            elements.until(
                expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'mat-autocomplete-']")))

            competences = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//mat-option[@role='option']//span")
            print(len(competences))

            for item in competences:
                print('options are', item.text)
                if item.text == 'Java Web Technologies':
                    item.click()
                    break
        except:
            print('Item was not found or Dropdown did not appear')`
```

Comment: you'll probably want a bit of sleep after entering the text and getting the "competences" array.  Include the exception(s) received in your question.  (Selenium's exceptions will tell you a lot about the issue...)

Comment: Hi! @browsermator, thanks for your inputs. I added selenium exception after removing custom one and was able to catch the missing closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

I added selenium exceptions after removing my custom exception and then found the error.  The  xpath wait locator had an error ie closing parenthesis was missing.

Wrong xpath locator used in the WebDriverWait:

WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
elements.until(
expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'mat-autocomplete-']")))

Correct xpath:
WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
elements.until(
expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@id,'mat-autocomplete-'**)**]")))

This was causing the code to fail. I wasted 2-3 days as my custom exception failed to catch the error